# Can I chain property in javascript and method together?

Tags: javascript

For example : 
I want to get the background color of body that is currently yellow and change it to blue:

```
   document.body.style.backgroundColor =  document.body.style.backgroundColor.replace("yellow", "blue");
```

It doesn't work, why?? Then how can I change the background color of the body using javascript??The main question is why I can't use `.replace` method on `document.body.style.backgroundColor`

Comment: Is the document body's background color really yellow? Please show us a JSFiddle of the code that you're currently using

Comment: Please explain how you are setting the colour to yellow in the first place. You can use `.replace()` on any string value, but is the `style.backgroundColor` property actually being reported as the string `"yellow"`? If you set the colour in your stylesheet the `style.backgroundColor` would come back as an empty string. Also, if you just want to set it to blue why don't you set it directly rather than trying to use `.replace()`? `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";`

Answer (score 1):

Following is enough:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

In your code, if `backgroundColor` *has* `yellow` it will replace with `blue`. If that is what you need I think it would be better to use `toLowerCase()` method before replacing.

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 
document.body.style.backgroundColor.toLowerCase().replace("yellow", "blue");
```

You can also use regular expression (as suggested by @nnnnnn) for case sensitive replace as;

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 
document.body.style.backgroundColor.replace(/yellow/i, "blue");
```

Comment: actually i change the background color differently.And I need to change the background color differently by refering to the previous value. The main question is why can't I use .replace method on my property?

Comment: You can use it and make sure it is `yellow` as js is case sensitive. try something like `document.body.style.backgroundColor.toLowerCase().replace("yellow", "blue");`

Comment: A case-insensitve replace is easier: `.replace(/yellow/i,"blue")`.

Comment: @nnnnnn (6n's), Updated with your suggestion. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thefourtheye/PexeK/

```
<body style="background-color:yellow">
    <input type="button" onclick="changeColor()" value="Change Color" />
</body>
<script>
    function changeColor() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = document.body.style.backgroundColor.replace("yellow", "blue");
    }
</script>
```